# std::ostream pointer initialization

Tags: c++, ostream

My program crashes without any error, so I'm asking for advice on this new topic I'm not familiar with.

Header file:

```
class CANLog
    {
public:
    CANLog( std::string file_name );
    CANLog( std::ostream* stream );
    ~CANLog(void);

private:
    typedef enum
    {
        FILE,
        STRINGSTREAM
    } string_type_t;

    std::ostream* output;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    string_type_t m_type;
    };
```

CPP file:

```
CANLog::CANLog( std::ostream* stream )
{
    m_type = string_type_t::STRINGSTREAM;
    output->rdbuf(stream->rdbuf());
}
...
```

Program crashes in the last line of the class constructor (`output->rdbuff...`). Why is that?

Comment: Your `output` pointer in `CANLog` constructor has not been initialized, it's not pointing to `nullptr` but some random garbage memory location, and using it in any way is Undefined Behavior, and most likely will crash your program

Comment: Which `std::ostream` do you think `output` is pointing to at that point?

Comment: I thought it doesn't matter that it points to random memory location, since I am changing it to point to the new stream buffer (in the class constructor) ?

Comment: `output->rdbuf(stream->rdbuf());` calls the `rdbuf` member-function on the `output` instance. You need an instance to do so.

Comment: @Kaldrr if I check with 'if (output == NULL)', the condition returns true.

Comment: @YSC How do I do that? Because the other solution I tried was declaring 'std::ostream output(NULL);' at the start of .cpp file, and then I could call rdbuf() on the output variable with no crashes.

Comment: You shouldn't use pointers if you're not confident with them. Try and use references maybe: `std::ostream& output;` which should be bound as `CANLog` init in the [member list initiliation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What is `stream` pointing to? What do you want `output->rdbuf(stream->rdbuf());` to do? Do you just need `output = stream` instead?

Comment: @YSC What do you mean, how are you supposed to learn anything than? Anyway, I cannot use references because I cant initialize the output variable to nullptr in member init list, because nullptr is a rvalue.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I want to save parameter variable 'stream' to variable 'output' and then use << operator on it: (*output) << "test";

Comment: a [mre] would help explain what you are trying to do but it does seem `output = stream` is all you need

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes thank you, I tried that, but then it crashes when I try to write to it with ' (*output) << "test"; '. Do you have an idea why? Even if I put that line into 'if (output)', to make sure the std::ostream is not null, it makes no difference.

Comment: not without a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles Minimal example works ok, so I think the problem is elsewhere. At least now I know where the problem isn't. Thanks!